# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.config'; '__main__' is not a package

Tags: python, модули

Есть следующая структура проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске python run.py:

```
import subprocess
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'telegram_bot/bot.py']).wait()
        if p:
            continue
        break
```

Появляется ошибка:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.config'; '__main__' is not a package
```

В bot.py вот такие импорты:

```
from .config import *
from database.db import cursor, connection
```

Я знаю, что можно перенести db.py в папку telegram_bot и сделать абсолютный импорт, но мне важна именно такая структура проекта, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Относительные импорты изменидись в питон 3. Убери точку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инструкция `subprocess.Popen(['python', 'telegram_bot/bot.py'])` запускает файл `bot.py`.

В нём у Вас находится инструкция `from .config import *` - относительный импорт.

Но относительный импорт нельзя использовать в файле, который Вы планируете запускать.
Вот [выдержка из документации](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) по этому поводу:

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current
>   module. Since the name of the main module is always `"__main__"`,
>   modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application
>   must always use absolute imports.

*Вольный перевод:*

> Обратите внимание, что относительный импорт основан на имени текущего
>   модуля. Поскольку имя основного модуля всегда `"__main__"`, модули,
>   предназначенные для использования в качестве основного модуля
>   приложения Python, всегда должны использовать абсолютный импорт.

Замените относительный импорт на абсолютный:

```py
from config import *
```

При такой структуре проекта, от импорта `database.db` придётся отказаться, либо явно указывать путь, по которому `Python` должен его искать:

```py
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, r"path\to\database")

from db import cursor, connection
```

Предупреждаю, что это ***временное*** решение.
Настоятельно рекомендую переделать структуру проекта, чтобы этого избежать.

Comment: Хорошо, а как быть c database.db? Выдает что такого модуля нет.

Comment: @MalMel Придётся отказаться от такого импорта, либо явно прописывать путь, по которому `Python` должен искать этот модуль. Рекомендую 1 вариант.

Comment: @MalMel Обновил ответ, укажите путь к модулю и, как временное решение, должно работать.

Comment: спасибо большое